# Spectral decomposition of some special matrices

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}a+b & a &0\\a & 2a & a\\0 & a & a+b \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}a+b & a &0 & 0\\a & 2a & a & 0\\0 & a & 2a & a\\0 & 0 & a & a+b \end{pmatrix}$, where $A$ and $B$ are invertible. Is it possible to find $A^{-1/2}$ and $B^{-1/2}$ such that $A^{-1} = A^{-1/2}A^{-1/2}$ and $B^{-1}=B^{-1/2}B^{-1/2}$?

Comment: It is possible if $A\geq $ and $B\geq 0$

Comment: I mean that $\langle Ax\mid x\rangle \ge 0$ for all $x$

Comment: yes they are positive definite.

Comment: So $A^{1/2}$ exists and we have $A=A^{1/2}A^{1/2}$

Comment: Yes. But is it possible to find analytical expressions for them?

Comment: You should try to find a solution.